# Cannot connect to Google Cloud Services on GCE instance using an external static IP Address

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google, vpc-peering

I‘m trying to connect to services hosted on Google Cloud, e.g. gcr.io (which is very important to me as my Docker images are hosted over there) via a GCE instance. Using an external static IP address this is not possible. However, using a "normal" external IP address, everything works perfectly fine.

I configured my own VCP network with a subnet (I used the standard/ recommended CIDR configuration by GCP).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have check the security group (it's a aws term but there should be a similar thing on GCP)? Also have you assigned that IP addr. to your instance?

Comment: Do you mean the firewall rules? Yes, I assigned it to my instance

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please clarify how you are trying to access and what error you are getting while trying to access the resource. Can you also confirm the normal Static external ip you mentioned is ephemeral IP?

If you would have no issue accessing using ephermal IP i suspect that the issue could be on repositary you are accessing.

Additionally I would recommend reviewing the documentation for troubleshooting while access the registry (gcr.io)

https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/troubleshooting

Comment: Yes, my normal external IP is an ephemeral IP.

I‘m getting a timeout error when accessing the repo and many other Google services (e.g. pinging google.com). All other services/ addresses outside the Google universe work. Pulling the image locally on my computer and on the same instance with an ephemeral IP works

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, it is now working. I guess it takes some time until the static external IP is fully usable. Thanks for comments!